# Excessive process time spent on java.lang.object.wait calls

Tags: java, parsing, optimization

As a new-ish Java user, I'm quickly falling in love with the language and using it in a number of projects to become familiar with it. In this case, I've written a basic log-parsing program (two objects for mapping log line types and a main 'API' script).

My problem is one of efficiency and optimization. I started to write the program using a 2MB log file of ~6300 lines, and would get run times of 0.30 - 0.50 seconds. When I ran the program on a significantly larger file (162MB, 465,000 lines) I was expecting it to be much longer, perhaps in the 1-2 minute range. What I wasn't expecting was an exponential increase in time at an estimated 40+ minutes for the operation to complete.

A bit of research with a Java profiler (JProfiler trial) has pointed out the following method taking up 30% of my execution time.

```
org.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.Worker.run
```

which is traced to

```
java.lang.Object.wait
```

I'm hoping to get some advice from the masters of Java who may have dealt with similar issues before, and could point me in the right direction.

Cheers!

EDIT:

Through multiple runs I've observed that the program starts off quickly, with the first 2000-3000 lines happening in a matter of seconds. Between 5000-11000 though, everything begins to slow to a crawl. That screams some sort of memory leak or allocation issue to me, but the profiler isn't reporting anything of the sort. Below I've attached a screenshot of a partial run with the larger file.

[Profiler showing 'hotspots'](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kbWuw.png)

Comment: Time spent in `Object.wait()` is almost definitely a red herring - a thread in that method is probably parked, and not actually consuming CPU resources. The fact that this is being called from an `org.eclipse` package also suggests that this thread is just a monitor thread run by your IDE, and not the program itself. I think you need to go back to your profiler and try to isolate the thread actually doing the work.

Comment: At a guess, a more likely cause of your slow-down might be memory pressure. What are you actually doing with the parsed contents of the file? If reading each line adds to the amount of stuff stored in memory, then it could be that for larger files, each garbage-collection cycle frees up less memory (because more is still needed), and so garbage collection is needed more frequently, slowing the program down. You could try increasing your max heap size (`-Xmx` on the command line) to see if that helps.

Comment: This is likely due to a poor choice of algorithm or data structure. Include an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), without the concrete code this will just end up in lots of guessing and waste of time on both ends.

Comment: @user31601 Thank you for pointing that out! I'll work through the filters and try to narrow down the thread.

I'm splitting each line by spaces, recording a number of the results in variables and constructing instances of a class that stores the line as a 'LogEntry'. The end goal is for this program to serve up lists of LogEntry objects for further searching and parsing.

I'm using java.util.Scanner and java.io.FileInputStream to read in lines of the files without having to commit them entirely to memory. I'll try increasing the heap size and report back!

Comment: @DanMašek Thanks for introducing me to the MCVE concept! Your point definetly made sense, and in the process of simplifying my code to post for you I actually seem to have isolated the source of my problem!

As expected, it was a beginner's mistake with a nested for-loop running at least four times every line.

Comment: @gsharpe Glad it helped and led you to figuring out the problem yourself. Was it all just what you described? That kind of performance degradation seems quite severe to be caused only by what you described. It might be worth plotting time vs input size for a number of sizes -- I'd expect log parsing to be fairly linear.

Comment: @DanMašek I'm certainly looking to plot some size/vs times to check how linear the process is, but that for loop was absolutely the culprit. I had split the string, then ran a for loop to add all the split strings past a certain index back together via a string builder every line. That load seemed to add up fairly quickly, when a embedded substring + String.indexOf() was much more efficient.

The profiler is now showing the majority of the work done being split between the FileInputStream and Scanner, which is more along the lines of what I expected. Still not blazing fast, but much better.